# Optimizing Haskell Inner Loops

Tags: optimization, haskell

Still working on my SHA1 implementation in Haskell. I've now got a working implementation and this is the inner loop:

```
iterateBlock' :: Int -> [Word32] -> Word32 -> Word32 -> Word32 -> Word32 -> Word32 -> [Word32]
iterateBlock' 80 ws a b c d e    = [a, b, c, d, e]
iterateBlock' t (w:ws) a b c d e = iterateBlock' (t+1) ws a' b' c' d' e'
    where
    a' = rotate a 5 + f t b c d + e + w + k t
    b' = a
    c' = rotate b 30
    d' = c
    e' = d
```

The profiler tells me that this function takes 1/3 of the runtime of my implementation. I can think of no way to further optimize it other than maybe inlining the temp variables but I believe -O2 will do that for me anyway.

Can anyone see a significant optimization that can be further applied?

FYI the k and f calls are below. They are so simple I don't think there is a way to optimize these other. Unless the Data.Bits module is slow?

```
f :: Int -> Word32 -> Word32 -> Word32 -> Word32
f t b c d
    | t <= 19   = (b .&. c) .|. ((complement b) .&. d)
    | t <= 39   = b `xor` c `xor` d
    | t <= 59   = (b .&. c) .|. (b .&. d) .|. (c .&. d)
    | otherwise = b `xor` c `xor` d

k :: Int -> Word32
k t
    | t <= 19   = 0x5A827999
    | t <= 39   = 0x6ED9EBA1
    | t <= 59   = 0x8F1BBCDC
    | otherwise = 0xCA62C1D6
```

Comment: Without trying, I'm guessing a lot of the issue is keeping your block data in a list (too much point/memory traffic).  I'd try hard to move to a unboxed vectors of `Word32` and manually unroll the loop.  Short of that, try it with a strict/unpacked structure holding `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, and `e`; then you'd only have one variable needing passed (and you'd be sure to put a bang pattern on it, right?).

Comment: I would also try to replace all the `(<=)` with a table lookup, though I'm not sure it will help much.

Comment: Another thing: It is often a good idea to write tight arithmetic functions in C and call that using the FFI. If you are careful to introduce no side-effects, the runtime can use a fast call into C that gives good performance.

Comment: But the C-calls still take a lot of cycles, so be sure you do enough work in C-land. For small things, it's better to smoke a few `MagicHash`es and use the GHC primops.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looking at the core produced by ghc-7.2.2, the inlining works out well. What doesn't work so well is that in each iteration a couple of `Word32` values are first unboxed, to perform the work, and then reboxed for the next iteration. Unboxing and re-boxing can cost a surprisingly large amount of time (and allocation).
You can probably avoid that by using `Word` instead of `Word32`. You couldn't use `rotate` from Data.Bits then, but would have to implement it yourself (not hard) to have it work also on 64-bit systems. For `a'` you would have to manually mask out the high bits.

Another point that looks suboptimal is that in each iteration `t` is compared to 19, 39 and 59 (if it's large enough), so that the loop body contains four branches. It will probably be faster if you split `iterateBlock'` into four loops (0-19, 20-39, 40-59, 60-79) and use constants k1, ..., k4, and four functions f1, ..., f4 (without the `t` parameter) to avoid branches and have smaller code-size for each loop.

And, as Thomas said, using a list for the block data isn't optimal, an unboxed Word array/vector would probably help too.

With the bang patterns, the core looks much better. Two or three less-than-ideal points remain.

```
                      (GHC.Prim.narrow32Word#
                         (GHC.Prim.plusWord#
                            (GHC.Prim.narrow32Word#
                               (GHC.Prim.plusWord#
                                  (GHC.Prim.narrow32Word#
                                     (GHC.Prim.plusWord#
                                        (GHC.Prim.narrow32Word#
                                           (GHC.Prim.plusWord#
                                              (GHC.Prim.narrow32Word#
                                                 (GHC.Prim.or#
                                                    (GHC.Prim.uncheckedShiftL# sc2_sEn 5)
                                                    (GHC.Prim.uncheckedShiftRL# sc2_sEn 27)))
                                              y#_aBw))
                                        sc6_sEr))
                                  y#1_XCZ))
                            y#2_XD6))
```

See all these `narrow32Word#`? They're cheap, but not free. Only the outermost is needed, there may be a bit to harvest by hand-coding the steps and using `Word`.

Then the comparisons of `t` with 19, ..., they appear twice, once to determine the `k` constant, and once for the `f` transform. The comparisons alone are cheap, but they cause branches and without them, further inlining may be possible. I expect a bit could be gained here too.

And still, the list. That means `w` can't be unboxed, the core could be simpler if `w` were unboxable.

Comment: I added bang patterns to all (!) parameters of all functions (except `ws`),  that made unboxing work.

Comment: Good find. You don't need bang patterns on _all_ parameters, though, with bangs on `a, b, c, d, e, a'` everything's roses, k and f are inlined, everything unboxable unboxed.

Comment: yeah. It's generally a good idea to put bang-patterns on arguments that are supposed to be strict.

Comment: Yes. I was fooled by GHC unboxing everything immediately in the loop body; with the traditional weakness in treating the fixed-width types, I didn't test.

Comment: Are you sure that LLVM won't optimize most of those narrows away?  I'd expect that to be likely.

Comment: Folks. There is lots of new info here to learn about Haskell optimizing. But some things aren't as obvious as it seems. For example, I tried replacing the k function by a Data.Vector.Unboxed vector and indexing it but it actually took longer.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I'm not sure about anything LLVM may or may not do. Currently I don't have an LLVM to check anyway.

Comment: @Ana It's not the k we're talking about when suggesting unboxed vectors/arrays, for that, there is a potential gain by splitting iterateBlock' and inlining them, not by hiding them in an array. It's the ws. Taking a boxed w from a list has a good chance to be slower than reading an unboxed w from an array. No guarantee, though, ghc is pretty good with lists.